# zurb-foundation top-bar sticky mobile

Tags: jquery, css, zurb-foundation

I'm using the zurb-foundation with the sticky top-bar.

When the site is in **mobile width,** it doesn't scroll smoothly.

It jumps half way down the page with the smallest scroll amount.

http://codepen.io/nathanw/pen/zxZaQQ

I want the page to scroll smoothly when the navigation is toggled open.

```
<div class="container sticky">
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar data-options="sticky_on: large">
    <ul class="title-area">
      <!-- Title Area -->
      <li class="name">
        <h1>
          <a href="#">
            Top Bar Title
          </a>
        </h1>
      </li>
      <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>menu</span></a></li>
    </ul>

    <section class="top-bar-section">
      <!-- Right Nav Section -->
      <ul class="right">
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Main Item 1</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </nav>
</div>
```

I think this might have something to do with the addition of the `<body style="" class="f-topbar-fixed">` and `<div class="container sticky fixed">` when the page is scrolled. I just don't know what to change to make it scroll through the entire page.

---

### Edit:

This is the behavior I get when the widow is in mobile width and the navigation is toggled open.

The scrolling jumps all the way down the page with the smallest amount of scroll.

See how "Your email" jumps all the way to right below the menu?

[image]

Comment: Can't recreate your issue

Comment: Are you in mobile width? With the navigation toggled? And **then** scrolling?

Comment: Yea, I don't see the issue you're describing.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this... I've added some screenshot to describe the issue I'm having.

Comment: i have no issues either

Comment: I've tried using Safari 7.1.2, Chrome 39.0.2171.95, Firefox(dev edition 36.0a2) and all of them have the same behavior... Scrolling 'jumps' way down the page. I've added an animated gif to show what's happening.

Comment: I can't replicate that at all. It's smooth on my screen. Mac 10.10 - Chrome

Comment: I also can't replicate it, tested with Chrome 40.0.2214.91 - Windows 8, it scrolls smoothly. Did you posted the full code?